# Searching PayPal subscriptions based on email

Tags: rest, paypal-subscriptions

We have PayPal subscribers who have signed up for recurring monthly payments using a PayPal generated button on our site. We are thinking about placing a paywall of sorts around some of our content.

Is there a way to search our subscriber list based on a user's email? I would like for the user to input his email on our site. Then, I'll use PayPal's REST API to see if they are an active subscriber based on that.

I've looked on PayPal's API documentation, and I can only find the ability to search by the user's ID.  https://developer.paypal.com/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_get

Does PayPal have any other REST functionality to search by email? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution not using the proposed one by @preston-phx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no functionality to search by email.

Set up a webhook listener subscribed to [`PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` events](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions), and keep your own record of the last time each subscription was paid for.